# Entity Framework - Count records with the same name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a customer table filled with customer detail and I would like to count all the records in that table and return how many records exist in the table for each name.

So if I have two customers with name Erik, and three records with name Roberts. The function would return two Eriks and three Robers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Customers.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => new { Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the group by part of linq for this

```
from grp in (
    from customer in customers
    group customer.Name by Customer.Name
 select new {Name = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count()};
```

That will give you an set of objects with a property "Name" and a property "Count" the count being how many customers with that particular name you have. Then you can use that information as needed